# Use numpy for FFT convolution

Tags: python, numpy, fft, padding, convolution

I have two arrays, `a` and `b` both of length N. I want to do, for example `j = 4`

```
import numpy as np
N = 1000
c = np.zeros(N)
j = 40
c[j] = np.sum([a[i] * b[(j-i)%(N-1)] for i in range(N)])
```

But if directly using convolution theorem, I would get

```
c[j] = np.sum([a[i] * b[j-i] for i in range(N)])
```

which is the same as

```
c = np.fft.ifft(np.fft(a) * np.fft(b))
```

Is there a clever way to pad zeros such that one index misalignment can be treated using `np.fft`, which is very fast.

Comment: What is “one index misalignment“? With FFT you get the first `c` (but with `%N`), not the second one, which would result in an index out of bounds.

Comment: I mean I want to module `(N-1)` but not `N`. The second one would not be out of bounds since `j `takes values from `0 `to `N-1 `since Python `range` does not include end point.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I somehow want numpy arraies to interpret -1 as the second last element but not the last element

Comment: I keep forgetting that you can use negative indices in Python. Still, it is unclear what you want. Maybe you want to pad the array by replicating the last elements at the beginning of the array, skipping the very last element?

Comment: Python is `0`-index based, so your `N`-elements array is indexed by `0,1,...,N-1`, and generally `j % N` is the correct operation, not `j % (N-1)`, because that returns `0` for both `0` and `N-1`.

Comment: @QuangHoang, indeed, a solution is added.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to first truncate the arrays so that the rolling back in `numpy.arrays`, e.g., index `-1` in the truncated arrays is the second last in the original one. For example,

```
import numpy as np
N = 100
a_arr = np.random.rand(N)
b_arr = np.random.rand(N)
c_arr = np.zeros(N)

for j in range(N):
    c_arr[j] = np.sum([a_arr[i] * b_arr[(j-i) % (N-1)] for i in range(N)])

# Truncated to the first N-1 elements.
a_arr_t = a_arr[:N-1]
b_arr_t = b_arr[:N-1]

# Use FFT for convolution for the truncated arrays. 
# So that rolling back -1 means the second last not the last.
c_arr_t = np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fft(a_arr_t) * np.fft.fft(b_arr_t))
for j in range(N-1):
    c_arr_t[j] += a_arr[N-1] * b_arr[(j-(N-1)) % (N-1)]

# The last element is treated separately.
c_arr_check = np.append(c_arr_t, np.sum([a_arr[i] * b_arr[(N-1-i) % (N-1)] for i in range(N)]))
print(np.max(c_arr_check - c_arr))
```

And finally add the tail element manually.

The total complexity for this is still `O(Nlog(N))` plus some `O(N)` operations to complement tails.